# simply way to handle post data/image in node js through Postman Form-Data

Tags: node.js, postman, multipartform-data

**Is there a way to post form-data through postman using Nodejs. I have seen many platforms but the author is using the front-end to post data which manipulates the back-end code. I want to understand the code**

Comment: what does this mean `Is there a way to post form-data through postman using Nodejs.`
postman is separate application and node js is separate, you either send data only from postman

Comment: I was talking about the Code section. 
```

Comment: It doesnt make sense how can you send a data from nodejs to nodejs using postman, you either use potman application to post data to nodejs or frontend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can send the data using form-data in post man.

You can see the formdata under the body section in this form data you have to change the type from `text` to `file`
[image: post man form-data]

after changing to file type you can browse your local machine. to choose the image

You can further parse the files in node js using `formidable`. You can install this package and you can configure to your needs. It can handle upto 1000 files

Coming to code part in node js.
First configure the formidable

```
const form = new formidable.IncomingForm({
      multiples: true,
      keepExtensions: true,
    });
```

After that you have to parse the `fieldvalue` and `file`

```
form.parse(req);
```

Then you can seperate the value and files uisng

```
form.on("file", (field, file) => {}) //For file
form.on("field", (fieldName, fieldValue) => {}) //for fieldvalue
```

Hope this one helps for you!!

Comment: what does it mean by multiples and KeepExtensions? and Form.On?

Comment: @NamaloomPakistani For uploading more than 1 files we have to set this configuration

Comment: `app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    form.parse(req);
    form.on("field", (fieldName, fieldValue) => {
        const x = req.email;
        const y = req.password;
    })
})`

Answer (score 1):

Sure thing. Set request type to POST and then define your data in the request body

check this out

https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/requests/#sending-body-data

Comment: I was talking about form-data

Comment: You can set form-data in the request body in postman. Just select File in the key section

Comment: but I am unable to manage it on Nodejs. The problem lies in understanding the code

Comment: So the correct question is how to handle form data using node js. Which framework are you using?